# Confused on a very simple "==" test

Tags: r, equality

How is this possible?

```
> a=TC_df$temp[561]
> a
[1] 15.6
> a==15.6
[1] FALSE
> a=="15.6"
[1] TRUE
> class(a)
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: I'm pretty confident this is a float inaccuracy, but out of spite, could you specify which programming language this is ?

Answer (score 1):

You compare a number with string with [`==`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Comparison) operator. Use [`identical`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/identical) instead.

Start with:

```r
> a=15.60000000000001
> a
[1] 15.6
> a=="15.6"
[1] TRUE
> a==15.6
[1] FALSE
```

A kind of such a number is in your case stored in the variable `a`.

The `options(digits...)` controls the number of digits to print when printing numeric values. Now set the number of digits to print to 16:

```r
> options(digits=16)
> a
[1] 15.60000000000001
> toString(a)
[1] "15.6"
```

Do you see what happened? The `identical` does not suffer from this problem.

Comment: Oh, yes thank you!! 
I didn't know that : as.character(15.600000000000000001) 
gives "15.6"

That was what confused me!

Thank you so much for your help!